# How to handle Single Quote

Tags: c#, sql-server, escaping

I have data with and without single quotes:

```
saed
sa'ed
```

I want both results whether the user entered `saed` or `sa'ed` into the search form.

```
 var lastName = request.LastName.IndexOf("*", 0, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) >= 0
      ? request.LastName.RemovePercentsign().ReplaceAsterikWithPercentSign()
      : request.LastName+ "%";
```

Comment: If you search of OBRYIAN (without quotes) how do you suppose to add the missing quote to retrieve the two records containig quotes? What rules should the C# code follow to add a quote in a random place inside the lastName text?

Comment: @Steve I think that he simply wants to ignore single quotes everywhere, whether they are in the database or the user entered them. So you don't need to insert quotes into random places in the input string, you need to remove them from the data you're comparing against.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore single quotes, then remove them:

```
lastName.Trim().Replace("'","")
```

Just swap that in where you currently have this:

```
lastName.Trim()
```

e.g.:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", lastName.Trim()));
```

Becomes:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", lastName.Trim().Replace("'",""));
```

Now, you didn't bother showing the code where you actually check the table, but there I suspect you will also need to do something like:

```sql
WHERE REPLACE(column,'''','') LIKE @LastName + '%';
```

To avoid forcing a scan of the entire table by applying this replace function to the column, you could consider creating a computed column with apostrophes removed (and persisting and/or indexing it) and checking against that column instead of the primary column (you want to keep the apostrophes there, rather than obliterating them completely, because you still want to display the data correctly).

Of course you will probably want to handle a set of other characters too, e.g. if someone enters `Moseley-Williams` or `MoseleyWilliams`, do you want both `Moseley-Williams` and `MoseleyWilliams` to come back? What about smart apostrophes (`’`)? What about errant characters anyone might have put in at data entry time *or* during the search? Do you want to correct user types like `Sm"th` or `Sm"ith`?

Comment: I have tried this.Its not working i am getting one record what ever i type.

Comment: @JuniorDev you might need to show more of your C# code, in particular the query text...

Comment: @JuniorDev also verify that we are talking about single quotes here (`'`), not those silly (smart) possessive quotes that Word likes to use (`’`).

Comment: I got the suggestion that i should uniform the data in database and apply search on it

Comment: We only have single quote in name as valid character other than that no character is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to achieve your goal if you change your query text to include the SQL Function [REPLACE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Supposing that your command text is the following

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE REPLACE(LastName, '''', '') LIKE @lastname";
```

Now if you prepare your parameter `@lastname` removing all quotes present in its value like [Mr Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) suggests

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastname", lastName.Trim().Replace("'",""));
```

You will retrieve all records in your test set above.
Be aware to check the performance of this query because I have a strong feeling that using REPLACE in this way will kill any kind of optimizer

Answer (score -1):

Basically you have to check for the presence of the single quote if it exist then add two more to it and insert it into the database:

use `lastName.Contains("\'")` to chcek and to replace it use `lastName.Replace("'","''")`